# Got error TS1005: '?' expected when try to run a type check command using TSC

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, reselect

Use `@reduxjs/toolkit` with `typescript`, when I try to run the `type-check` npm script, I get an error:

```bash
$ npm run type-check

> ts-1005@1.0.0 type-check
> tsc --project tsconfig.json --pretty --noEmit

node_modules/reselect/dist/reselect.d.ts:8:122 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

8 type LongestTuple<ArrayOfTuples extends readonly unknown[][]> = ArrayOfTuples extends [infer FirstArray extends unknown[]] ? FirstArray : ArrayOfTuples extends [
                                                                                                                           ~

node_modules/reselect/dist/reselect.d.ts:11:1 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

11 ] ? LongerOfTwo<FirstArray, LongestTuple<RestArrays>> : never;
   ~


Found 2 errors.
```

`src/index.ts`:

```
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "ts-1005",
  "scripts": {
    "type-check": "tsc --project tsconfig.json --pretty --noEmit"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "dist"]
}
```

Not sure why `skipLibCheck` configuration does not work. Or, `@reduxjs/toolkit` is incompatible with TS `4.3.2`?

I have checked the peer dependencies of RTK 2.0.1, there is no `typescript`.

```bash
$ npm view @reduxjs/toolkit@2.0.1 peerDependencies
{
  react: '^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18',
  'react-redux': '^7.2.1 || ^8.1.3 || ^9.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrading the RTK to v1.9.7 solves the problem. You will find it uses `"reselect": "^4.1.8"` [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.9.7/packages/toolkit/package.json#L104)

Check [`package.json`](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/blob/v4.1.8/package.json):

```bash
"types": "./es/index.d.ts",
"typesVersions": {
  "<4.2": {
    "*": [
      "./src/legacyTypes/ts4.1/index.d.ts"
    ]
  }
},
```

`reselect` package will use [Version selection with
typesVersions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#version-selection-with-typesversions) to figure out which TS type definition files it needs to read.

On TS version 4.2 and above, it will use `./es/index.d.ts`, otherwise, it will use `./src/legacyTypes/ts4.1/index.d.ts`

On TS version 4.2 and above, there is no [`extends` Constraints on `infer` Type Variables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables) in the [v4.1.8/src/types.ts](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/blob/v4.1.8/src/types.ts) file.

On TS version <4.2, see below testing:

[image]

Downgrading the TS to v4.1, Go to the definition for `createSelector`, and `reselect` package will use `./src/legacyTypes/ts4.1/index.d.ts` as its type definition.

Run `type-check` npm script again:

```bash
$ npm run type-check

> type-check
> tsc --project tsconfig.json --pretty --noEmit
```

The error is gone.

Answer (score 4):

`extends` Constraints on `infer` Type Variables has been added in [TS 4.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables).

This is why your TS 4.3 compiler is complaining.

Also, you can notice that the latest version of `@reduxjs/toolkit` requires TS 5.2 as peer dependency.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I can't upgrade the TS version. The choice is to downgrade the RTK to v1？I also checked the peer dependencies of RTK v2, and did not find TS

Comment: I seem to be able to use TS 4.8.4 okay with Redux-Toolkit 2.0.1, for what it's worth.